# joins supported in sharded MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: mongodb, join, google-cloud-platform, data-warehouse, rockset

I'm trying to evaluate MongoDB Atlas on GCP, and had a few basic questions regarding joins.

- What the different types of joins supported ?
- Are these joins supported in a sharded cluster as well ?

I see a few people trying to use joins on MongoDB, though i believe it might not be the most natural use-case for MongoDB

Pls let me know!

tia!

Update :
Anyone used MongoDB + Rockset, seems Rockset + MongoDB Atlas can be used to enable complex SQL joins .
pls see link :
https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/joins-and-aggregations-using-real-time-indexing-on-mongodb-atlas

Comment: Like many other NoSQL databases MongoDB the join capabilities are limited. The only operation is [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is equal to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Regarding restrictions see [Sharded Collection Restrictions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#sharded-collection-restrictions)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - thnx, any experience with Rockset ? seems Rockset + MongoDB Atlas can be used to enable complex SQL joins . pls see link : https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/joins-and-aggregations-using-real-time-indexing-on-mongodb-atlas

Comment: I don't know Rockset. Perhaps "aggregations and JOINs" is just a marketing phrase. With left outer join you can create also other join operations. In general NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins! Typically in a NoSQL database you have much lower number of collections than in according number of tables in a relational RDBMS. You need to design your application properly, usually it is bad to make a collection/table one-to-one translation.

Comment: I work for Rockset, and it is designed to provide SQL on top of NoSQL. Not only is it capable of joins, but there are a few different JOIN options that can provide some impressive performance for analytic use cases. Mongo is still a great product and has its place in the architecture, handling transactions, low latency writes and key-value lookups. Rockset indexes the data in order to support 'regular' SQL on top of semi-structured, schemaless data and keeps up with changes in Mongo within a few seconds. Connecting to Atlas takes about 2 minutes, and you can be up and querying in no time.